# getting unique index's value from multiindex

Tags: python, pandas

df is a dataset looking like below. column name, date is a multiindex and the value is the corresponding data(which stands for equity's price in dollars)

```
                               value
name             date               
122630 KS Equity 2013-01-02  13495.0
                 2013-01-03  13400.0
                 2013-01-04  13195.0
                 2013-01-07  13220.0
                 2013-01-08  12960.0
                 2013-01-09  12850.0
                 2013-01-10  13080.0
                 2013-01-11  12910.0
                 2013-01-14  13050.0
                 2013-01-15  12765.0
                 2013-01-16  12570.0
                 2013-01-17  12595.0
                 2013-01-18  12690.0
                 2013-01-21  12735.0
                 2013-01-22  12880.0
                 2013-01-23  12630.0
                 2013-01-24  12415.0
...                              ...
278240 KS Equity 2018-03-19  22855.0
                 2018-03-20  23690.0
                 2018-03-21  23275.0
                 2018-03-22  22285.0
                 2018-03-23  19460.0
                 2018-03-26  21110.0
                 2018-03-27  21080.0
                 2018-03-28  20535.0
                 2018-03-29  21605.0
                 2018-03-30  21785.0
291630 KS Equity 2018-03-16   9980.0
                 2018-03-19   9680.0
                 2018-03-20  10025.0
                 2018-03-21   9865.0
                 2018-03-22   9420.0
                 2018-03-23   8225.0
                 2018-03-26   8930.0
                 2018-03-27   8915.0
                 2018-03-28   8680.0
                 2018-03-29   9165.0
                 2018-03-30   9230.0
292340 KS Equity 2018-03-20  10050.0
                 2018-03-21  10050.0
                 2018-03-22  10090.0
                 2018-03-23   9750.0
                 2018-03-26   9815.0
                 2018-03-27   9925.0
                 2018-03-28   9745.0
                 2018-03-29   9890.0
                 2018-03-30   9970.0
```

The question is "How can I make a unique datetime dataset which comprises all the date in the above but not the duplicates?

```
all_dates = [datetime(2013,1,2,0), datetime(2013,1,3,0), datetime(2013,1,4,0),...datetime(2018,3,29,0), datetime(2018,3,30,0)]
```

I tried `df.index(1).value` but it gives error `''MultiIndex' object is not callable'`

Comment: Can your provide some example data for your `df`? Otherwise this is impossible to replicate.

Comment: @jpp, I edited my question according to your request. Sorry that I provide insufficient information

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html) first, then [`unique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.unique.html) and last convert to `list`:

```
L = df.index.get_level_values('date').unique().tolist()
print (L[:10])
[Timestamp('2013-01-02 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2013-01-03 00:00:00'), 
 Timestamp('2013-01-04 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2013-01-07 00:00:00'), 
 Timestamp('2013-01-08 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2013-01-09 00:00:00'), 
 Timestamp('2013-01-10 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2013-01-11 00:00:00'), 
 Timestamp('2013-01-14 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2013-01-15 00:00:00')]
```

For pure python datetimes add [`to_pydatetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.to_pydatetime.html):

```
L = df.index.get_level_values('date').unique().to_pydatetime().tolist()
print (L[:10])
[datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 2, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 3, 0, 0), 
 datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 4, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 7, 0, 0), 
 datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 8, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 9, 0, 0), 
 datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 10, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 11, 0, 0), 
 datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 14, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 15, 0, 0)]
```

Comment: @HannahLee - give me a sec for convert to python datetimes

Comment: In recent versions of pandas `df.index.unique('date').tolist()` avoids building the full values array.

Answer (score 0):

```
all_dates = []
df = df.reset_index()
for item in list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(df['date'])):
    all_dates.append(datetime.strptime(item, "%Y-%m-%d"))
print(all_dates)
>>> [datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 2, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 3, 0, `0), datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 4, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 7, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 8, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 9, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 10, 0, 0), ...,datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 26, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 27, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 28, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 29, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 30, 0, 0)]`
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: I think it is best practice to avoid "For" loops (if possible) when working with pandas and numpy. It will decrease your running time SACRIFICIALLY. (The core reason, I think, Is the implementation of those packages in C language)

Answer (score 0):

You can use below technique to extract only unique dates from list of dates:

li = sorted(all_dates)

print([li[d] for d in range(0, len(li)) if not (li[d] == li[d-1] or (d< len(li)-1 and li[d] == li[d+1]))])

Comment: Thnks ANK for your comment~!!:)